# 'For' versus 'toward'

Tags: word-choice

Are these sentences both grammatical ?

> - "This is a big step **towards** the project's completion."
> - "This is a big step **for** the project's completion."

If so, how do we decide between the first and the second one?

Comment: The second one means "the project completion made a big step."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because we're thinking of the project's completion as a distant place, saying *towards* makes sense, and *for* does not.

If you didn't want to use *towards*, you could change "the project's completion" to something more tangible.

> This is a big step for a part of the project.

Or you could try something that acts on the progressiveness of the goal

> This will speed the project's completion.
>
> This will hurry the project's completion.

Answer (score 0):

The second question is incorrect for what you want to express.

Comment: Would the second one be incorrect replacing 'to' with 'for'? More generally, is it possible to substitute 'toward' with different word? If so, what is this word? Thank you in advance.